# Run Lizmap stack with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postgis, docker-machine

I tried installing lizmap with docker compose on an ubuntu machine. In the desktop version I can log in to localhost. I'm trying to connect with 0.0.0.0 so as to simulate connecting from outside the machine (like a server)
I changed the pointing to LIZMAP_PORT=${LIZMAP_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8090"} by entering 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1
When I connect from the outside, I can see the login form, in a minimal version without graphics. I log in and see the lizmap page but as soon as I click it gives me 500 errors
How can I solve it? I would also like to have a secure server setup
[text](https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-docker-compose/tree/master)
this is the variables of env.default

```
COPY_COMPOSE_FILE=0
LIZMAP_VERSION_TAG=${LIZMAP_VERSION_TAG:-"3.5"}
QGIS_VERSION_TAG=${QGIS_VERSION_TAG:-"3.22"}
POSTGIS_VERSION=${POSTGIS_VERSION:-"13-3"}
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-"postgres"}
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB=${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB:-"lizmap"}
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER=${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER:-"lizmap"}
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD:-"lizmap1234!"}
QGIS_MAP_WORKERS=${QGIS_MAP_WORKERS:-"1"}
WPS_NUM_WORKERS=${WPS_NUM_WORKERS:-"1"}
LIZMAP_PORT=${LIZMAP_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8090"}
OWS_PORT=${OWS_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8091"}
WPS_PORT=${WPS_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:8092"}
POSTGIS_PORT=${POSTGIS_PORT:-"127.0.0.1:5432"}
POSTGIS_ALIAS=${POSTGIS_ALIAS:-"db.lizmap"}
```

I ran the commands and everything works in localhost:8090.
Trying to expose 0.0.0.0 as a variable the frontend opens but any page gives me 500 errors

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that means "all interfaces"; in a Docker context it's important to _listen_ on "all interfaces" but it doesn't make sense to connect to it.  Just that shell script fragment doesn't seem like enough to reproduce your problem; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't understand how to do it. the goal is that I have to install everything on a server and therefore I thought of using 0.0.0.0 to reach the machine. currently the framework only works with localhost